# Cannot connect to RDP when TOR is enabled

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I have a bit of a weird scenario. I use a VPN to connect to my home network and once there I use Remmina to RDP into my Windows machine. I connect to the TOR network using Tallow and once I do that my machine kicks me off RDP. I know that I need to change some network configurations of Tallow but I’m not sure what to do